# .net listbox trigger event on select from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

when I am trying to trigger an event on select from listbox asp.net user control in **ie 7 8 9**

```
$("select").trigger("change")
$("select").trigger(jQuery.Event("change", {target: $("select").get(0)}));
$("select").trigger(jQuery.Event("change", {srcElement: $("select").get(0)}));
```

**predefined .net script fails in the predefined function that no one can change**

```
function ValidatorOnChange(event) {
  if (!event) {
      event = window.event;
  }
  Page_InvalidControlToBeFocused = null;
  var targetedControl;
  if ((typeof(event.srcElement) != "undefined") && (event.srcElement != null)) {
      targetedControl = event.srcElement;
  }
  else {
      targetedControl = event.target;
  }
  var vals;
  if (typeof(targetedControl.Validators) != "undefined") {
      vals = targetedControl.Validators;
  }
  else {
      if (targetedControl.tagName.toLowerCase() == "label") {
          targetedControl = document.getElementById(targetedControl.htmlFor);
          vals = targetedControl.Validators;
      }
  }
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
      ValidatorValidate(vals[i], null, event);
  }
  ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
}
```

because **event is suddenly null** it cannot find `event.target.Validators` or `event.srcElement.Validators`. How to trigger change event properly?

Comment: You can use `$(this)` in your event handler; seems much easier than your code and it refers to the current `select` (you seem to be triggering `change` on all the selects but trying to always pass the first one)

Comment: this posted script is predefined .net script which noone can change!

Comment: Technically, you could override `ValidatorOnChange()` by simply including a script that defined it at some point in your html after the original script was included.

Comment: oops, sorry. Why is the event suddenly null? Can you debug this code to see where it fails?

Comment: this is the first function in the call stack. event is suddenly null

Answer (score -1, accepted):

during .net generated script investigation I have over 9000 facepalm per second.

I think that if you are noob you should learn before write something. but over 9000 microsoft's indians doesn't think so

```
var original_trigger = $.fn.trigger;
$.fn.trigger = function(type, data) {
    if($.browser.msie) {
        $(this).each(function() {
            window.ValidatorOnChange({
                target: this
            });
        });
        return $(this).trigger("CustomChange", data);
    }
    return original_trigger.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

this is bad too. the best way is to list change listeners, remove indian's ValidatorOnChange listener and rebind it properly. but unfortunately i have no many time to delve into this sh*t

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to trigger with `$("select").change();` and handle the event with `$("select").change(function(){ //code here });`

Comment: .net listbox is one of the listeners that bind to select's change. I want to trigger events to all listeners